# internet explorer and target event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i hope you can help me!
This function doesn't work in internet explorer! How can i do?

```
function docClick (oEvent) {
    var bHide = true, oTable = document.getElementById("content_tab");
    for (var oItTarget = oEvent.target; oItTarget; oItTarget = oItTarget.parentNode) {
        if (oItTarget === oTable) { bHide = false; break; }
    }
    if (bHide) {
        oTable.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you can mention the browser version also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `currentTarget` property for IE. Check what target is available:

```
var oItTarget = oEvent.target ? oEvent.currentTarget : oEvent.target;
```

Or in your function:

```
function docClick (oEvent) {
    var bHide = true, oTable = document.getElementById("content_tab");
    for (var oItTarget = oEvent.target ? oEvent.currentTarget : oEvent.target; oItTarget; oItTarget = oItTarget.parentNode) {
        if (oItTarget === oTable) { bHide = false; break; }
    }
    if (bHide) {
        oTable.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: No. If `target` isn't available (as it isn't in IE < 9) then neither is `currentTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `srcElement` rather than `target` in IE < 9. You may also (depending on how the event handler is attached) need to use `window.event` in IE.

```
function docClick (oEvent) {
    oEvent = oEvent || window.event;
    var target = oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement;

    var bHide = true, oTable = document.getElementById("content_tab");
    for (var oItTarget = target; oItTarget; oItTarget = oItTarget.parentNode) {
        if (oItTarget === oTable) { bHide = false; break; }
    }
    if (bHide) {
        oTable.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```